# React / Apollo: Displaying Error of GraphQL mutation (useMutation hook)

Tags: python, reactjs, django, graphql, react-apollo

I am having a hard time trying to figure out why I can't show the error of my mutation.

I have implemented error codes in my mutation:

```
if location_lat < 0.1 and location_lon < 0.1:
            raise GraphQLError('E_CF_002')
```

now on the client-side, I  call the following mutation, which is called onSubmit of a form and I purposefully trigger the error.

```
const [
    createEvent,
    { data: createData, loading: createLoading, error: createError}
  ] = useMutation(CREATE_EVENT);
```

The error code is successfully returned as seen in my network tab:

```
{"errors": [{"message": "E_CF_002", "locations": [{"line":
```

However, when I try to show the error in a dialogue box

```
        {createError && (
          <div>
            <Dialog open={openDialog} onClose={handleClose}>
              <h3>Sorry, an error occured while creating the event.</h3>
              <h3>Plese try again later. {JSON.stringify(createError)} </h3>
              <DialogActions>
                <Button onClick={handleClose} color="primary">
                  Okay
                </Button>
              </DialogActions>
            </Dialog>
          </div>
        )}
```

I only see:

```
Sorry, an error occured while creating the event.
Plese try again later. {}
```

Can anyone help me understand why my error variable does not hold the message etc.?

I first tried directly printing createError.message or createError[0].message or even createError.errors and even createError.errors[0] however later on I saw that even the entire JSON is empty by printing JSON.stringify(createError).

I haven't been able to find this specific issue (or it's solution) on StackOverflow or elsewhere.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/data/queries/#inspecting-error-states ... and 'Error handling' parts ?

Comment: @xadm I have also tried `useMutation(CREATE_EVENT, { errorPolicy: 'all' });` and also tried printing afterwards `{JSON.stringify(createError.graphQLErrors)}` both had no effect if I print the graphQLErrors I don't even get the `{}` string ,it's completely empty then.

Comment: console.log it before rendering block, before return JSX ... inspect component with browser react dev tools